# Django: how to set initial value for Date Range Filter in Admin Model

Tags: python, django

I am new developer in Django. I have a admin site with Django.
I have a table with 1.600.000 registries. I need to filter by range of date, and i need define start date and end date in a Django filter Date Range Filter.

I am using,

> Django==2.1.10
> django-admin-rangefilter==0.5.0
> virtualenv==16.7.2
>
> python-3.7.3

```
class TrackAdmin(ExportActionMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('timestamp', 'get_tipomarca','get_point','get_emp')
    search_fields = ('point_id', 'attendancetext')
    list_per_page=20
    list_filter = (
        ('timestamp', DateRangeFilter),
    )
```

I view that filter in my site admin in Django.But I expect  the textbox of "from date" has a value, example, 23/08/2019 and textbox of "to date" has a date today.
With this parameters, I have a filter a query with only registry necessary and not all table.

That is my current view:
[Current view with filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmgBj.png)
And expect that:
[Expect view with filer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avRrO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.strptime("21-06-2014", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("07-07-2014", "%d-%m-%Y")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

// and return range with your function, that you have not put.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't understand where i use this code.

Answer (score 0):

In my Admin Model class, added a list_filter and i did overwrite def get_queryset(self, request):

```
    start = datetime(2019, 7, 1)
    end = datetime.now()
    qs.filter(timestamp__range=[start, end])
```

I filtered the queryset with initial dates, so the query not return all objects.(1.500.000 objects)
Initialy , with the DataRangeFilter, I hoped to set default values in textbox in the widget, but it's not was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The library tries to access default getters for each of the fields. Please see [this PR](https://github.com/silentsokolov/django-admin-rangefilter/pull/57/files) as an example.

Ultimately the solution would like as follows:

```
class TrackAdmin(ExportActionMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('timestamp', 'get_tipomarca','get_point','get_emp')
    search_fields = ('point_id', 'attendancetext')
    list_per_page=20
    list_filter = (
        ('timestamp', DateRangeFilter),
    )

    def get_rangefilter_timestamp_default(self, request):
        return ('2021-01-01', '2021-02-01')
```